# Is there a confirmation for submitting an application?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I clicked Apply on a posting on SO Careers, pasted in a cover letter, imported my resume from profile and was then presented with a preview of my resume. There were two buttons at the top of the page "Attach to application" and "Preview PDF". Clicking either of them took me back to the job posting.

I was expecting to see some kind of confirmation message or an email message, but did not see either. So I either applied twice, or not at all.

Is there supposed to be some kind of confirmation? Is this a bug? I'm using Chrome 24 with Adblock Plus disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes there is a confirmation page

However, it appears the link back to the application after the application is currently broken.  I'll make sure it's restored first thing in the morning.

### Workaround

You can continue your application once you are returned to the job listing page by clicking the apply button at the bottom once again.  I have tested that all of the information including attaching the resume is happening correctly, it's just missing the argument which restores the application window.  If you click the apply button and continue using the already attached resume you will be able to submit your application correctly.

### How to tell when you have applied to a job

If you have ever applied to a job, you will see a messages link next to your user name at the top of the screen.  That link will take you to your messages page which will have a tab for `Job Applications` that lists all of your applications.  Each of your applications can be viewed by clicking on them.

Comment: The workaround does indeed work. Thank you!

Comment: The link back to the application is now fixed.